# How to implement a java script version of monero CPU miner

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cpu-mining, mining, javascript

Coin-hive.com implements a java-script version of monero cpu miner. Which we can insert on our website to mine monero through the users CPU power. Can Someone provide me leads on how this works on the backend. Does this works on C++ or java-script solely and how can i implement my own version of this?

Comment: Have you looked at [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site itself says they've used WebAssembly to compile C code to Javascript. This means you'd need to be competent in C in order to attempt this feat.

If you work through the numbers though, the revenue you'd get from asking your visitors to mine Monero will be tiny compared to the advertising revenue you could get instead. I'd also imagine Google will soon start blacklisting sites that do this.

Comment: why would they blacklist sites ?

Comment: The same reason that they penalize other types of low quality web sites and ad-heavy sites. See https://www.bespoke-digital.co.uk/guides/google-fred/

Comment: I hope they don't blacklist sites I hope this could be a viable alternative to ads however it shouldn't be penalised

Comment: true this is a viable alternative to ads, it should not be penalised, and i am also looking to make a javascript web miner, but i dont know where to start, 

where shall i start to make my own javascript web  miner?